# How to add a picture to a table in sql(with parameters)

Tags: sql-server, image, stored-procedures

I have the code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_AddUser
    @Name Nvarchar(50), 
    @LastName Nvarchar(50), 
    @PictureAddress nvarchar(50)
As
Begin
    Insert tbl_Users(Name, LastName, Picture) 
       Select 
           @Name, @LastName, BulkColumn 
       From 
           OpenRowSet(Bulk 'c:\s.jpg', single_blob) as img 
End
```

Well this code works but when I change the address of the image to `@PictureAdress` like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_AddUser
    @Name Nvarchar(50), 
    @LastName Nvarchar(50), 
    @PictureAdress nvarchar(50)
As
Begin
    Insert tbl_Users(Name, LastName, Picture) 
        Select 
           @Name, @LastName, BulkColumn 
        From 
           OpenRowSet(Bulk @PictureAdress, single_blob) as img 
End
```

It won't work. The error is

> Incorrect syntax near '@PictureAddress'. Excepting String or Text_Lex

What can I do? Thank you for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are not allowed in OPENROWSET statements.  You must use dynamic sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_AddUser
    @Name Nvarchar(50), 
    @LastName Nvarchar(50), 
    @PictureAdress nvarchar(50)
As
Begin

DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SET @sql = '
        Select 
           '+@Name+', '+@LastName+', BulkColumn 
        From 
           OpenRowSet(Bulk '+@PictureAdress+', single_blob) as img 
';

 Insert tbl_Users(Name, LastName, Picture) 
 EXEC (@sql);
```

End